# How do I query via php spamhaus ip blacklist

Tags: php, spam

Trying to query `spamhaus.org` for blacklisted ip. An example is `69.35.160.59`
If I go to `https://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/` and enter it, it shows on blacklist same with `112.198.83.17`, however the following code returns an empty array.

I print out the url and it looks correctly formatted in reverse ip
`17.83.198.112.zen.spamhaus.org`.

Any ideas?

```
<?php

    $ip = "112.198.83.17";
    $blacklist = "zen.spamhaus.org";
    $url = implode(".", array_reverse(explode(".", $ip))) . ".". $blacklist;
    echo "$url<br>";
    $record = dns_get_record($url);
    print_r ($record);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doing right. See here for result codes http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage#366

Here is my output for ip 69.35.160.59

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => 59.160.35.69.zen.spamhaus.org
            [type] => A
            [ip] => 127.0.0.4
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 900
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [host] => 59.160.35.69.zen.spamhaus.org
        [type] => TXT
        [txt] => http://www.spamhaus.org/query/bl?ip=69.35.160.59
        [entries] => Array
            (
                [0] => http://www.spamhaus.org/query/bl?ip=69.35.160.59
            )

        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 900
    )
```

Comment: Must be my hosting blocking it. Using hostgator. Tried on another shared also and didn't work.
Tried on dedicated server and did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Just make sure you are not using public dns resolvers like 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 because the code will not work if you do so.
You can check what resolvers you are using by viewing the file /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Not just public resolvers, but even the resolvers from large ISPs *might* be blocked by spamhaus, if their reason for blocking certain DNS resolvers is based on the number of queries received.  The most reliable option is to run your own recursive name server locally.  I use `pdnsd` but you could also use `bind9` or `unbound`.  It needs to be in recursive mode, not forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple function that returns true if listed with SpamHaus. Any incoming IPs are checked and either allowed or blocked:

```
function callSpamhaus($UserIP) {
    // NON-INFECTED IP FOR TESTING
    // 192.99.150.120
    // INFECTED IP FOR TESTING
    // 216.145.14.142
    $blacklist = "zen.spamhaus.org";
    $url = implode(".", array_reverse(explode(".", $UserIP))) . ".". $blacklist;
    $record = dns_get_record($url);
    if (is_array($record) && !empty($record)) :
        return TRUE;
    endif;
}
```

A conditional is run upon each access to the site that runs the function, using whatever method you choose to fetch the IP and create a variable for it:

```
$SpamHaus = callSpamhaus($IPAddress);
if ($SpamHaus === TRUE) :
     Redirect("/administration/accessblocked.php");
endif;
```